# Photoshop Not Saving Image at Specific Dimensions

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export

I'm trying to export my Photoshop artboards as 800x800px jpgs. I hit Export As and changed the dimensions to 800x800px. It shows me it's scaling it down. Great. I hit Export All, and it saves the jpgs where I tell it. When I then go check the file dimensions - one of the artboards won't save as 800x800px! I tried again and can see that in the Export dialogue box it WON'T let me put those dimensions in, but has to change them to 754x800px. Why in the world? It can scale it to other dimensions, just not that one..?! Please help!

Comment: Sounds like one of your artboards doesn't have a 1:1 aspect ratio.  Check the size of the troublesome artboard.  Make sure it's a 1:1 aspect ratio.

Comment: But I've exported the same artboard before and gotten the 800x800px result! Can this still be the issue?

Comment: Could you have accidentally resized the artboard?

Comment: Thing is my artboards are all 2000x2000px, and I'm just scaling them down when I export...